# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `id` is marked as required in `User`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs

/* 0.chunk.js:33320 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `id` is marked as required in `User`, but its value is `undefined`.
at User (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:231:5)
at Users (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:384:1)
at div
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:109:1)
at UserProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:460:5)*/

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import UserConsumer from "../context";

class User extends Component {
  state = {
    isVisible: false,
  };
  //Destructing
  static defaultProps = {
    name: "bilgi yok",
    salary: "bilgi yok",
    department: "bilgi yok",
  };

  onClickEvent = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      isVisible: !this.state.isVisible,
    });
  };

  onDeleteUser = (dispatch, e) => {
    const {id} = this.props;
    //Consumer Dispatch
    dispatch({ type: "DELETE_USER", payload: id });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, department, salary } = this.props;
    const { isVisible } = this.state;
    return (
      <UserConsumer>
        {(value) => {
          const { dispatch } = value;
          return (
            <div className="col-md-8 mb-4">
              <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <h4 className="d-inline" onClick={this.onClickEvent}>
                    {name}
                  </h4>
                  <i
                    onClick={this.onDeleteUser.bind(this, dispatch)}
                    className="far fa-trash-alt"
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  ></i>
                </div>
                {isVisible ? (
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <p className="card-text">Maas : {salary}</p>
                    <p className="card-text">Department : {department}</p>
                  </div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </UserConsumer>
    );
  }
}

User.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  salary: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  department: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

User.defaultProps = {};

export default User; /* Başka classlarda kullanılmak için export edildi*/
```

Comment: Where is this used? We should inspect to the component that <User /> is used.

Comment: The `id` prop passed to `User` is going to be `undefined` for at least one life-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import User from "./User";
import UserConsumer from "../context";

class Users extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <UserConsumer>
        {(value) => {
          const { users } = value;
          return (
            <div>
              {users.map((user) => {
                return (
                  <User
                    key={user.id}
                    name={user.name}
                    salary={user.salary}
                    department={user.department}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </UserConsumer>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

//This is where  is used

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).